# How to display the last ordered product in WooCommerce via a shortcode

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, product, shortcode, orders

I'm looking for a way to display the last ordered product on another page.

I think it would be possible to maybe create a shortcode in the functions that takes the order details and displays them wherever I add the shortcode.

[image: Here is an example of what I mean.]

---

But I can't seem to figure out how to get it to work. So far I got this information to work with:

```php
add_shortcode( 'displaylast', 'last' );
function last(){
    $customer_id = get_current_user_id();
    $order = wc_get_customer_last_order( $customer_id );
    return $order->get_order();
}
```

`[displaylast]` is currently showing me noting. It does work when I change `get_order()` to `get_billing_first_name()`.

That displays the order name. But I can't seem to get the item that was bought. Maybe there is a `get_()` that I'm not seeing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are close, however you must obtain the last product from the order object.

So you get:

```php
function last() {
    // Not available
    $na = __( 'N/A', 'woocommerce' );
    
    // For logged in users only
    if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) return $na;

    // The current user ID
    $user_id = get_current_user_id();

    // Get the WC_Customer instance Object for the current user
    $customer = new WC_Customer( $user_id );

    // Get the last WC_Order Object instance from current customer
    $last_order = $customer->get_last_order();
    
    // When empty
    if ( empty ( $last_order ) ) return $na;
    
    // Get order items
    $order_items = $last_order->get_items();
    
    // Latest WC_Order_Item_Product Object instance
    $last_item = end( $order_items );

    // Get product ID
    $product_id = $last_item->get_variation_id() > 0 ? $last_item->get_variation_id() : $last_item->get_product_id();
    
    // Pass product ID to products shortcode
    return do_shortcode("[product id='$product_id']");
} 
// Register shortcode
add_shortcode( 'display_last', 'last' );
```

---

SHORTCODE USAGE

In an existing page:

```
[display_last]
```

Or in PHP:

```
echo do_shortcode('[display_last]');
```